# NullReferenceException in DotNetOpenAuth

Tags: asp.net-mvc, oauth, nuget, dotnetopenauth, integrated-pipeline-mode

I tracked down what appears to be a defect causing a NullReferenceException in my ASP.NET MVC app. Did I break this, or should this break DotNetOpenAuth for the majority of installations?

I get this:

```
[NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.]
   DotNetOpenAuth.AspNet.OpenAuthSecurityManager.GetUsername(HttpContextBase context) +27
   DotNetOpenAuth.AspNet.OpenAuthSecurityManager.RequestAuthentication(String returnUrl) +341
   Controllers.LoginController.Index() +226
```

Here's the `Index()` method. Note it currently returns **User** in production and **OK** in development. Those are obviously temporary. The commented code is from the last URL I referenced below, where I reduced the amount of code between me and the problem. The stack trace was still similar, though.

```
public virtual ActionResult Index()
{
    if (HttpContext == null) return Content("HttpContext");
    if (HttpContext.User == null) return Content("User");
    if (HttpContext.User.Identity == null) return Content("Identity");
    return Content("OK");
    new OpenAuthSecurityManager(HttpContext, s_fbClient, OAuthDataProvider.Instance)
        .RequestAuthentication(Url.Action(Actions.Callback()));
    // OAuthWebSecurity
    //  .RequestAuthentication("facebook", Url.Action(Actions.Callback()));
    return null;
}
```

The exception arises because `HttpContext.User` is null. [Here's the `DotNetOpenAuth.AspNet` library source](https://github.com/matejskubic/dotnetopenid/blob/master/src/DotNetOpenAuth.AspNet/OpenAuthSecurityManager.cs#L263) for that failing method.

```
private static string GetUsername(HttpContextBase context) {
    string username = null;
        if (context.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated) {
            username = context.User.Identity.Name;
        }
    return username ?? string.Empty;
}
```

`User` has apparently has [been nullable ever since IIS Integrated Mode was available](http://chocosmith.wordpress.com/2012/07/03/httpcontext-current-user-is-null-with-iis-7-integrated-mode/). This explains why I don't see it in development, as I'm running IIS Express with defaults, but it doesn't explain why I can't find any information about the defect. Integrated mode was released in 2007, and DotNetOpenAuth is still maintained. Microsoft docs say this about the setting:

> Classic Mode: Use this mode only when the applications in the
>   application pool cannot run in Integrated mode.

I must be missing something, because it seems like everyone should have this issue.

Have I NuGet'ed a non-maintained library somehow? It seems odd, since it shows it was just updated a week ago. But when I follow the documentation link from NuGet, [the source code I arrive at](https://github.com/DotNetOpenAuth/DotNetOpenAuth) doesn't seem to even have an AspNet namespace, where my exception arose.

EDIT: The only related package I use is currently [DotNetOpenAuth.AspNet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/DotNetOpenAuth.AspNet/4.3.4.13329) (and it has 8 dependencies), last published less than a week ago. I've tried other packages also. I don't need `SimpleAuth` or any WebMatrix jazz. In the process of resolving this, I tried switching libraries as described http://techblog.dorogin.com/2013/06/Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages.OAuth.html

EDIT: Logged a defect related to this, but it seems this library may not be maintained. https://github.com/DotNetOpenAuth/DotNetOpenAuth/issues/317#issuecomment-29580565

EDIT: Pending stack trace, it may be the same defect as [MVC 5 Owin Facebook Auth results in Null Reference Exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19564479/mvc-5-owin-facebook-auth-results-in-null-reference-exception)

Comment: It seems to me that the `context` you're injecting is the wrong one.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, Michael, I do not inject `context`. What you are looking at is a piece of code from the DotNetOpenAuth library, the full source of which is linked above.

Comment: I think he was suggesting that you are passing the wrong context in.  Can you show the code from the LoginController's Index method?

Comment: Sure, Phil. Pasted above. Note that with the WebMatrix package, I didn't even pass `HttpContext`, as the library pulled it from static properties.

Comment: If I understand you, Phil, I'm not sure what HttpContext would be expected to have a non-nullable `User` property.

Comment: I can't speak for Michael, but I misread the stack trace, and thought you were calling GetUserName directly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is indeed a defect in the DotNetOpenAuth.AspNet code. Unfortunately that DotNetOpenAuth library is no longer maintained. Modifying the source with:

```
private static string GetUsername(HttpContextBase context) {
    string username = null;
        if (context.User != null && context.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated) {
            username = context.User.Identity.Name;
        }
    return username ?? string.Empty;
}
```

Of course does the trick.