# Facebook Login Asp.net Mvc Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, oauth, facebook-oauth

I'm learning asp.net mvc.I'm trying to do sample application with visual studio mvc template.
Login system ok for google but i have problem about signing with facebook account.
At the first step is done.
I'm redirected Associate your Facebook account page.
When i entered my Username and click the button i'm getting Object reference not set to an instance of an object for "info" variable at the blow code.

```
  public async Task<ActionResult> ExternalLoginConfirmation(ExternalLoginConfirmationViewModel model, string returnUrl)
        {
            if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
            {
                return RedirectToAction("Manage");
            }

            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                // Get the information about the user from the external login provider
                var info = await AuthenticationManager.GetExternalLoginInfoAsync();


                if (info == null)
                {
                    return View("ExternalLoginFailure");
                }

                var user = new ApplicationUser() { UserName = model.UserName };
                var result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user);
                if (result.Succeeded)
                {
                    result = await UserManager.AddLoginAsync(user.Id,info.Login);
                    if (result.Succeeded)
                    {
                        await SignInAsync(user, isPersistent: false);
                        return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
                    }
                }
                AddErrors(result);
            }

            ViewBag.ReturnUrl = returnUrl;
            return View(model);
        }
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I had the same exact issue and solved it by [updating the Facebook Nuget Packet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Owin.Security.Facebook/2.1.0). 
After some research I finally found out the solution thanks to the information given in [this StackOverflow question&answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19564479/mvc-5-owin-facebook-auth-results-in-null-reference-exception).