# How to add an ADFS user to `AspNetUsers` in Identity?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity, adfs, ws-federation

We have an on premises ADFS server that we have been successfully using to "authenticate" users on our web apps. However, it seems that this is working by pure magic, and is not functioning as it should.

### Goal

My goal is to have Identity set up on the web app and add ADFS as an external provider. If a user logs in via ADFS, a new Identity account will be created in `AspNetUsers`, and an entry will be added to `AspNetUserLogins` linking the AD account used to the Identity account just created.

### Current Behavior

Right now, my users are sent to the ADFS page and log in. Upon returning to my app, the `ExternalLoginCallback` function is called, `loginData` is set to `NULL`, and the if statement exits the method. For some reason, it still authenticates the user though, and they have full default access to the app. There is just no record of that user in Identity, and I cannot set up roles or 2FA for the account.

### Question

How can I change what I am currently doing in order to get this to function as desired?

### Code

**Startup.Auth.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Linq;
using System.Security.Claims;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Web;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin;
using Microsoft.Owin;
using Microsoft.Owin.Security;
using Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies;
using Microsoft.Owin.Security.WsFederation;
using Owin;
using TexasRelocation.Models;

namespace TexasRelocation
{
    public partial class Startup
    {
        private static string realm = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:Wtrealm"];
        private static string adfsMetadata = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:ADFSMetadata"];
        private static string reply = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:Wreply"];

        public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            // Configure the db context, user manager and signin manager to use a single instance per request
            app.CreatePerOwinContext(ApplicationDbContext.Create);
            app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationUserManager>(ApplicationUserManager.Create);
            app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationSignInManager>(ApplicationSignInManager.Create);
            app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationRoleManager>(ApplicationRoleManager.Create);

            // Enable the application to use a cookie to store information for the signed in user
            // and to use a cookie to temporarily store information about a user logging in with a third party login provider
            // Configure the sign in cookie
            app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
            {
                AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
                LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login"),
                Provider = new CookieAuthenticationProvider
                {
                    // Enables the application to validate the security stamp when the user logs in.
                    // This is a security feature which is used when you change a password or add an external login to your account.  
                    OnValidateIdentity = SecurityStampValidator.OnValidateIdentity<ApplicationUserManager, ApplicationUser>(
                        validateInterval: TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30),
                        regenerateIdentity: (manager, user) => user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(manager))
                }
            });
            app.UseExternalSignInCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);

            // Enables the application to temporarily store user information when they are verifying the second factor in the two-factor authentication process.
            app.UseTwoFactorSignInCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.TwoFactorCookie, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5));

            // Enables the application to remember the second login verification factor such as phone or email.
            // Once you check this option, your second step of verification during the login process will be remembered on the device where you logged in from.
            // This is similar to the RememberMe option when you log in.
            app.UseTwoFactorRememberBrowserCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.TwoFactorRememberBrowserCookie);


            app.SetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);

            app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions());

            app.UseWsFederationAuthentication(
                new WsFederationAuthenticationOptions
                {
                    Wtrealm = realm,
                    MetadataAddress = adfsMetadata,
                    Wreply = reply,

                    Notifications = new WsFederationAuthenticationNotifications()
                    {
                        SecurityTokenValidated = notification =>
                        {
                            //string employeeID = "";
                            string upn = "";
                            foreach (var claim in notification.AuthenticationTicket.Identity.Claims)
                            {
                                //if (claim.Type == "employeeID") 
                                //{
                                //    employeeID = claim.Value;
                                //}
                                if (claim.Type == ClaimTypes.Upn)
                                {
                                    upn = claim.Value;
                                }
                            }

                            ClaimsIdentity identity = notification.AuthenticationTicket.Identity;
                            //identity.AddClaim(new Claim("employeeID", employeeID));
                            identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Upn, upn));

                            return Task.FromResult(0);
                        }
                    }
                });
        }
    }
}
```

**AccountController.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Linq;
using System.Security.Claims;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.IdentityModel;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin;
using Microsoft.Owin.Security;
using TexasRelocation.Models;

namespace TexasRelocation.Controllers
{
    [Authorize]
    public class AccountController : Controller
    {
        private ApplicationSignInManager _signInManager;
        private ApplicationUserManager _userManager;
        private ApplicationRoleManager _roleManager;
        ApplicationDbContext context;

        public AccountController()
        {
            context = new ApplicationDbContext();
        }

        public AccountController(ApplicationUserManager userManager, ApplicationSignInManager signInManager, ApplicationRoleManager roleManager)
        {
            UserManager = userManager;
            SignInManager = signInManager;
            RoleManager = roleManager;
        }

        public ApplicationSignInManager SignInManager
        {
            get
            {
                return _signInManager ?? HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Get<ApplicationSignInManager>();
            }
            private set
            {
                _signInManager = value;
            }
        }

        public ApplicationUserManager UserManager
        {
            get
            {
                return _userManager ?? HttpContext.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>();
            }
            private set
            {
                _userManager = value;
            }
        }

        public ApplicationRoleManager RoleManager
        {
            get
            {
                return _roleManager ?? HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Get<ApplicationRoleManager>();
            }
            private set
            {
                _roleManager = value;
            }
        }

        //
        // GET: /Account/Login
        [AllowAnonymous]
        public ActionResult Login(string returnUrl)
        {
            if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
            {
                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
            }

            ViewBag.ReturnUrl = returnUrl;
            return View();
        }

        //
        // POST: /Account/Login
        [HttpPost]
        [AllowAnonymous]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<ActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel model, string returnUrl)
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return View(model);
            }

            // This doesn't count login failures towards account lockout
            // To enable password failures to trigger account lockout, change to shouldLockout: true
            var result = await SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.Email, model.Password, model.RememberMe, shouldLockout: false);
            switch (result)
            {
                case SignInStatus.Success:
                    return RedirectToLocal();
                case SignInStatus.LockedOut:
                    return View("Lockout");
                case SignInStatus.RequiresVerification:
                    return RedirectToAction("SendCode", new { ReturnUrl = returnUrl, RememberMe = model.RememberMe });
                case SignInStatus.Failure:
                default:
                    ModelState.AddModelError("", "Invalid login attempt.");
                    return View(model);
            }
        }

        //
        // POST: /Account/ExternalLogin
        [HttpPost]
        [AllowAnonymous]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult ExternalLogin(string provider, string returnUrl)
        {
            // Request a redirect to the external login provider
            return new ChallengeResult(provider, Url.Action("ExternalLoginCallback", "Account", new { ReturnUrl = returnUrl }));
            }

        // GET: /Account/ExternalLoginCallback 
        [AllowAnonymous]
        public async Task<ActionResult> ExternalLoginCallback(string returnUrl)
        {
            var loginInfo = await AuthenticationManager.GetExternalLoginInfoAsync();
            if (loginInfo == null)
            {
                return RedirectToAction("Login");
            }

            // Sign in the user with this external login provider if the user already has a login 
            var result = await SignInManager.ExternalSignInAsync(loginInfo, isPersistent: false);
            switch (result)
            {
                case SignInStatus.Success:
                    return RedirectToLocal();
                case SignInStatus.LockedOut:
                    return View("Lockout");
                case SignInStatus.RequiresVerification:
                    return RedirectToAction("SendCode", new { ReturnUrl = returnUrl, RememberMe = false });
                case SignInStatus.Failure:
                default:
                    // If the user does not have an account, then prompt the user to create an account 
                    ViewBag.ReturnUrl = returnUrl;
                    ViewBag.LoginProvider = loginInfo.Login.LoginProvider;
                    return View("ExternalLoginConfirmation", new ExternalLoginConfirmationViewModel { Email = loginInfo.Email });
            }
        }

        //
        // GET: /Account/ExternalLoginFailure
        [AllowAnonymous]
        public ActionResult ExternalLoginFailure()
        {
            return View();
        }

        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing)
            {
                if (_userManager != null)
                {
                    _userManager.Dispose();
                    _userManager = null;
                }

                if (_signInManager != null)
                {
                    _signInManager.Dispose();
                    _signInManager = null;
                }
            }

            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }

        //
        // POST: /Account/LogOff
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult LogOff()
        {
            //AuthenticationManager.SignOut(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
            Request.GetOwinContext().Authentication.SignOut();
            return RedirectToAction("Login", "Account");
        }

        #region Helpers
        // Used for XSRF protection when adding external logins
        private const string XsrfKey = "XsrfId";

        private IAuthenticationManager AuthenticationManager
        {
            get
            {
                return HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication;
            }
        }

        private void AddErrors(IdentityResult result)
        {
            foreach (var error in result.Errors)
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("", error);
            }
        }

        private ActionResult RedirectToLocal()
        {

            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
        }

        internal class ChallengeResult : HttpUnauthorizedResult
        {
            public ChallengeResult(string provider, string redirectUri)
                : this(provider, redirectUri, null)
            {
            }

            public ChallengeResult(string provider, string redirectUri, string userId)
            {
                LoginProvider = provider;
                RedirectUri = redirectUri;
                UserId = userId;
            }

            public string LoginProvider { get; set; }
            public string RedirectUri { get; set; }
            public string UserId { get; set; }

            public override void ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context)
            {
                var properties = new AuthenticationProperties { RedirectUri = RedirectUri };
                if (UserId != null)
                {
                    properties.Dictionary[XsrfKey] = UserId;
                }
                context.HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication.Challenge(properties, LoginProvider);
            }
        }
        #endregion
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Through a significant amount of extended research, I was able to figure out what my problem was. Please reference my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27506913/mvc5-owin-ws-federation-authenticationmanager-getexternallogininfoasync-return/59633933#59633933).